# ERROR: Keytool error:java.lang.RuntimeException::Usage error, ûgenkey is not a legal command

Tags: android, certificate, alias, keystore

I wanna upload my app in the market.

In order to upload app, I need to sign my application using my own personal certificate.

But I get error while generating certificate.

Command in CMD :`keytool –genkey –v –keystore nainesh.keystore –alias nainesh –keyalg RSA –validity 10000`

ERROR:

```
Keytool error:java.lang.RuntimeException::Usage error, ûgenkey is not a legal command
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally i solve the problem and the correct working script / Command is below: Please note the double quotes where they are placed please use as it is as this is the correct method. and off course please change the user name and as for the different versions of windows you people will have to change it accordingly. Please feel free to ask if you people have any questions.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keys
tore "c:\documents and settings\user\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android
 -keypass android
```

Answer (score 1):

keytool –genkey –v –keystore nainesh.keystore –alias nainesh –keyalg RSA –validity 10000

Here the issue is, "-" character not pasted correctly in the command prompt due to which it's giving an error that "ûgenkey" is not a legal command.

My suggestion is, try to edit manually provide the "-" character wherever you found in the command and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Keytool

```
-exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore 


  "C:\Documents and Settings\Ruben Antony\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 

-binary | openssl base64
```